# Running a batch file on multiple remote computers and checking the results

Tags: batch-file, psexec

I'd like to run a batch file on multiple remote computers at once. I saw that it is possible by doing:

```
psexec @computers.txt -d -n 5 cmd /c \\server\folder\file.BAT
```

However, since -d allows the script to run without waiting for the batch script to finish, I can't know if the run of the script succeeded in each remote computer.

Is there some way I can get feedback in real time from the remote computers if the run succeeded or not? Can I collect the output from all of the computers in real time?

Answer (score -1):

In the batch file add /L "C:\temp\results.log" this will create a file with results of the output on each computer it runs on.

Comment: OP didn't ask about script output, he asked about run status.